# Physical Adresses on a frame.

Tags: cisco, ethernet, mac-address

If I want to send a frame of 1kb size to a destination, and the frame has to go through other devices such as routers, bridges, hubs and other computers, how will the physical addresses of the sender and receiver change on the frame through  the road it reaches the destination?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Frames will not cross layer-3 boundaries (routers). The layer-2 addresses will remain unchanged on the layer-2 domain, but the frame will be stripped when it encounters a layer-3 device.